# glm: how can you compute logLik on new data?

Tags: r, glm

I've applied logistic regression using `glm` in R as follows:

```
 model <- glm(y ~ x, family=binomial(link='logit'), data=training_data)
```

Now I want to compute the log-likelihood of observing my test data given `model`, so I can see if it's doing better than other models.

[logLik](https://rdrr.io/r/stats/logLik.html) computes the log-likelihood of observing the training data given the model -- this is precisely the parameter that was maximised during model fitting. But how do I get the log likelihood of observing the test data given the model?

Answer (score 0):

```
prob=predict(model, newdata=..., type="response")
```

If you do: `?predict.glm` you will be able to see how to specify the type argument for the appropriate values.

And, thanks to Ben Bolker's comment - to complete the answer: `sum(log(prob*resp + (1-prob)*(1-resp)))`.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Let's make it reproducible: `m = glm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars[1:20, ])`. I can do `predict(m, data = mtcars[21:32, ], type = "response")` to get predictions for the rest of the data set, but it doesn't give the log likelihood. And the phrase "log likelihood" is not used on the `?predict.glm` help page.

Comment: starting from these probabilities, compute `log(prob*resp + (1-prob)*(1-resp))`